# Angular2 RC4 testing: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: testing_1.expect(...).toBeAnInstanceOf is not a function

Tags: testing, angular, karma-jasmine

Here is my test in Angular2:

```
it('should initialize without DI service',
         async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
           var template = '<component></component>';
           return tcb.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, template)
               .createAsync(TestComponent)
               .then((fixture ) => {
                 expect(fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance).toBeAnInstanceOf(ComponentType);
                 expect(fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance.state).toBeNull();
               });
         })));
```

It throws the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   testing_1.expect(...).toBeAnInstanceOf is not a function

It works fine in Angular2 RC2 till I updated to RC4.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been unanswered for a long time, this other post might be helpful for the future:

[Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468669/uncaught-typeerror-ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function)